# Get Value of other cells DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi I have sucessfully managed to make datagrid with checkbox but i have no idea how to get the state of checkbox it is checked or unchecked.I was recommended to use INotifyPropertyChanged.
of CellEditEnding event handler.Please help me i donot know how can i implement any one of these.

what i want is that check the value of checkbox which is checked/uncheked by user click. and can get the row index as well as value in first cell of that row.

My code so far is

```
namespace embeddatagridcheckbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<checkedBoxIte> item = new List<checkedBoxIte>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                checkedBoxIte ite = new checkedBoxIte();
                ite.MyString = i.ToString();
                ite.MyBool = false;
                item.Add(ite);
            }
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = item;
        }
    }

    public class checkedBoxIte
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XML is

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="323" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" BeginningEdit="dataGrid1_BeginningEdit">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyString" Binding="{Binding MyString}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyBool" Binding="{Binding MyBool}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is used when you change object in the C# code and want to update an interface. Opposite changes (from a UI to an object in code) work by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want to reference the CheckBox value from? Normally I would work with the DataGrid's ItemSource object directly instead of with figuring out rows/columns, but that depends on what you are trying to do.

In your example, you would find the state of the checkboxes in your list named `list` in the Code Behind, since that is what your datagrid is bound to.

`list[0]` = first row's data

`list[0].MyBool` = Checkbox value of first row